# CSS issue- inline-block is not working

Tags: css

I am trying to place two elements side by side. I used css inline block but surprisingly its not working.

```
<div class="item-body" style="display:inline-block">
    <!--- Element 1--->
    <div style="width:150px;" class="input-group">
        <div class="spinner-buttons input-group-btn">
            <button ng-click="selectedItem.qnt=selectedItem.qnt===1?1:selectedItem.qnt-1;updateSelectedItemData();" class="btn spinner-down red" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" style="text-align: center;" ng-model="selectedItem.qnt" maxlength="3" class="spinner-input form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength">
        <div class="spinner-buttons input-group-btn">
            <button ng-click="selectedItem.qnt=selectedItem.qnt+1;updateSelectedItemData()" class="btn spinner-up green-haze" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- Element 2--->
    <div > x {{i.item_qnt}}={{item_subtotal}}</div>
</div>
```

Element 1 and element 2 is appearing in different line

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen with the code, including CSS?

Comment: you did inline block on their container, you have to put it on the divs themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `display: inline-block;` to each element that you want to be displayed in the same line, **not** to their parent container. I've added background-color so it's clearly visible where each `<div>` is exactly located. For both inline-blocks to be aligned vertically, use css property `vertical-align`.

```css
.item-body > div {
  vertical-align: text-top;  
}
```

```html
<div class="item-body">
    <!--- Element 1--->
    <div style="display: inline-block; width:150px; background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <div>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" style="text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <button>+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- Element 2--->
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color: #ddd;"> x {{i.item_qnt}}={{item_subtotal}}</div>
</div>
```